# Draw on canvas, smoothly scale and draw something more

Tags: java, android, drawing, android-canvas

I have a trouble with scaling bitmap and then draw on it in Android. From the beginning, I have a custom view, with onDraw method, I'm drawing something on it's canvas. Now, I want to scale that drawing smoothly (still on canvas) and then draw something on that canvas, without clearing it (over that scaled drawing). How to accomplish this?

I have tried scaling whole view with build-in animation mechanism. Scaling is smooth, but it is not the way, because it is scaling whole component, not only the drawing. Is there any way to scale drawing smoothly and then draw on it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: drawing smoothly means like an animation?

Comment: Yes, I'd like it to be scaled with animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement the scaling animation by yourself. You could call `invalidate()` as long as you need to scale and measure the time between the `onDraw()` calls and calculate the amount of scaling you need. The scaling itself would be simply done by a call to `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint)` where your matrix must represent the scaling.

Another method would be to use [ScaleAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html) where the [Transformation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Transformation.html) contains a matrix you could use, too.

Drawing over the bitmap is simply done: just draw on the same canvas in `onDraw()` after you have drawn the scaled image. As only the image scales, the new drawn stuff is not scaled.

A third solution might be a bit more complex. You could, instead of scaling the bitmap, just scale the canvas. Scale down the canvas, draw the bitmap on it and restore the canvas. After that you can draw the rest.

Comment: I like the effect of ScaleAnimation, but it should be done on what? On my custom view?

Comment: Basically you should just start the animation and use `getTransformation()` to get the Transformation object and the matrix via `getMatrix()` on the transformation. With that matrix you should be able to scale the bitmap.